# keep www in url to match certificate domain in tomcat only environment

Tags: java, url, tomcat, dns

I have a Thawte certificate on my root server and a java (wicket) application running on tomcat only. the certificate is a standard webserver certificate and it is signed for www.somedomain.com . Indeed it is not trusted under somedomain.com (without www) . The DNS zone ist setup with the correct A entry and with a cname for www. I need to do some kind of dns forwarding to my domain with www prefix.

Any solutions to  solve this without apache webserver in tomcat only environment? I would not like to do a dirty workaround, only clean, user and searchengine friendly solutions

UPDATE

Although I'd rather kept tomcat standalone, the only way to solve that was to use a http proxy (in my case nginx) which listens to domains names through virtual hosts and rewrite the url to its www.* version and passing all requests for this new url to tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to either change the DNS so it has a correct A entry (you own it right?).  Or go back to Thawte and ask them for another cert that identifies your server using *.somedomain.com then it can be used for both www.somedomain.com and somedomain.com.

This might work for you otherwise:

http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: What do you mean with setting a correct A entry? My domain has the Servers IP address as its A entry, which additional entries can be made to achieve what I need to do? Also, I do not need a wildcard certificate, I just need to forward requests to the www prefixed domain like, for example, amazon is doing it. I did recognize the urlrewrite tool before, Ill take a closer look to it

Comment: the manual of urlrewrite said the url mapping is context reltive, I do not see any way to accomplish what I am trying to do through this tool. Do you have an example configuration of urlrewrite which would do a forward to my domain with www prefix?